# Does a web application built on Go's http package work as a single process using multiple threads to deal with incoming requests?

Tags: multithreading, go, process

I read that a Go application receives connections directly from clients using a built-in web server, not running behind a web server such as Apache. Also, I read network servers, such as Apache, deal with incoming requests using multiple processes created by fork(). 
Is this also true for a Go application, or does it operate on a single process and handle incoming requests by multiple threads?

Comment: Check out https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/ and look for GOMAXPROCS in particular.

Answer (score 2):

Go applications typically use the net/http package to implement a web server.  The [documentation for that package](https://godoc.org/net/http#Serve) says:

> Serve accepts incoming HTTP connections on the listener l, creating a new service goroutine for each. The service goroutines read requests and then call handler to reply to them.

Goroutines are scheduled on one or more OS threads.

The package does not use fork.